# Xamarin - unable to get a round launcher icon for Android 7.1 +

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, icons

Following this guide:
https://blog.xamarin.com/round-launcher-icons-in-android-7-1/?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog&utm_source=googleplus&utm_content=android-round-launch-icons

Using Visual Studio for Mac - latest stable channel release - Android SDK Manager: Android 7.1 SDK installed

However I don't get a round launcher icon on my Android 8.0 device - I only see the normal non-round icon. Anyone have an idea on what I am missing? Thanks.

Comment: What device are you trying it on?

Comment: @SushiHangover a OnePlus One with an unofficial AOSP 8.0 ROM

Comment: AOSP does not use round icons by default.

Comment: Map, Chrome, Drive, GMail has all rund icons

Comment: In terms of round icons, this is launcher specific, i.e. the ***Pixel*** Launcher supports round icons. Have you tried just running it on a Pixel Oreo-based emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. I was *not* about round icons - it was about Adaptive Icons. Adaptive Icons is an Android 8.0 feature.

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html